# UInt64 vs string in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I store a big information in one table, the records go to about 1 bilion recors. I assume that after some time it will go above 4 bilion which is maximum of uint32. So I am wondering is uint64 faster than string in this case? Clickhouse has good performance using partitions, but sometime I am going to search not inside partitions. So, which of them has good performance?

Answer (score 0):

Uint64 is faster than String.

But I assume that question is more complicated.

If you need to decode Uint64 identifiers into Strings at some point then it could be the opposite.